# Does this function vector<int> help(257, -1); creates 257 vectors with -1 elements each?

Tags: c++

*I'm trying to understand the significance of choosing the array size as (257, -1) in the help vector.*

```
 class Solution {
        public:
            int lengthOfLongestSubstring(string s) {
                vector<int> help(257, -1);
                int n = s.size(), ans = 0, curr = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                    if (help[s[i]] != -1) {
                        int temp = help[s[i]];
                        for (int x = curr; x <= temp; x++) {
                            help[s[x]] = -1;
                        }
                        curr = temp+1;
                    }
                    help[s[i]] = i;
                    ans = max(ans, i-curr+1);
                }
                return ans;
            }
        };
```

Comment: `vector<int> help(257, -1);` creates a `vector` named `help` with `257` elements with a value of `-1`.

Comment: but why are we creating only 257 not more than that?

Comment: @AdarshDhital Why do you think you need more than 257? Looking at the code (which is bugged) I can't see, even after fixing the bugs, why 256 is not enough.

Comment: @AdarshDhital I guess that you think that 257 is the maximum length of the string that can be checked. If that is what you think then you have misunderstood the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Does this function vector help(257, -1); creates 257 vectors with -1 elements each?

No, it creates *1 vector* with *257 values* that are all initialized to *-1*. See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector constructor #3. The first parameter is count of elements, the second is the initial value for each element.

> So why are we using only (257,-1) over here?

I'm not entirely sure about this and you need to ask the author to be absolutely sure. It looks like each element of the vector stores the index of the last occurence of a character:

```
help[s[i]] = ...
```

`s[i]`, which is used as index to `help` here, will return a `char`, which can take 256 different values. With this in mind, we can see that the largest possible index will be 255. That's where the size comes from (though 256 should suffice).

**But it's not that easy**: When input is restricted to ASCII-characters (0-127) this will work, however C++ allows `char` to be a signed type, i.e. on some systems `char` can be -128 to 127 instead of 0 to 255 which the author apparently expects. In this case, on some system, for certain inputs, you would try access a negative index on `help`, which is undefined behaviour.
See also https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types for more details on `char`.